# How to pass a result of find command to the mvn command using xargs?

Tags: bash, maven, xargs

**Note:** I don't want to use `find ... exec ...` because in this way maven errors are ignored.

I am trying to find all `pom.xml` within given folder and execute `mvn` on them. But I have an issue with proper passing `find` results to the `xargs` function. This:

`find ./maven_projects -name 'pom.xml'  -print0 | xargs -0 mvn clean package -f`

is not working. I receive kind of this error in maven:

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "./maven_projects/project1/pom.xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found how to solve it. The trick is to wrap a filename into an argument and pass it as this:

```
find ./maven_projects -name 'pom.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 sh -c 'mvn -f "$0" clean package'
```